# Grails GORM behaving strangely

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am experiencing the following very strange behavior with Grails GORM queries...

NOTE: I have 20 instances of `MyDomain` created. I.e `20 records`

**CASE 1**

```
 List<MyDomain> case1Results = MyDomain.where {
            (isTypeA == true) && (relation1.relation2.relation3.organization == org)
 }.list()
```

In this case, `case1Results` is an empty list.

**CASE 2**

```
 List<MyDomain> case2Results = MyDomain.where {
                (isTypeA == true)
 }.list()
```

In this case, `case2Results` contains the `20 records` I have stored.

This all seems to find up to this point. This shows that the 20 records are not associated with `organization`. However...

**THE PROBLEM:**

when I take `case2Results` and do the following...

```
println(case2Results.every {
    it.relation1.relation2.relation3.organization == org
}) //true
```

I get `true`

**OR:**

```
case2Results = case2Results.findAll{
    it.relation1.relation2.relation3.organization == org
}
```

Here, `case2Results` still contains `20 records` as in **CASE 2** above, not 0 as in **CASE 1**

I can't wrap my head around this behavior and I don't even know how to explain this if not with these examples. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

**PS:** Each of my domain classes has a belongsTo and hasMany static maps, creating relationships between the domain classes.

**PS:** This behavior is being experienced when I run unit tests but works well in the actual feature being tested.

Comment: are you missing a parenthesis in case 1 to close off (relation1.relation2.relation3.organization == org) <-- or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: what you do smells with overstretching. Such queries with 4 joins usually cost a lot of performance

Comment: @injecteer what are my alternatives? The relationships are established that way from the design of the database tables. Organization has many relation3, which has many relation2, which has many relation1 which has many myDomain.

On the other hand, myDomain belongs to relation1, which belongs to relation2, which belongs to relation3 which belongs to an organization.

Comment: What is the expected result count? 0, 20 or something in between? Also, you could enable sql logging and see whats happening on the database. http://sergiodelamo.es/log-sql-grails-3-app/

Comment: The expected count is 20. All the records are associated with the organization and `isTypeA` is true for all of them